# Node.js forEach loop of aws method

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services

I am trying to execute code after a forEach loop has finished, this is a simplified version of my problem:

```
var arr = { values: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'] };

arr.values.forEach(function (element) {
    ec2.describeInstances({ InstanceIds: ['i-51ec7d83'] }, function (err, data) {
        console.log(data.Reservations[0].Instances[0].Tags[0].Value);
    });
});

console.log('Excecute this after.');
```

However the result is:

> Excecute this after.
>
> Test1
>
> Test1
>
> Test1
>
> Test1
>
> Test1

I thought forEach loops were syncronous, why is this happening? What can I do?

Thanks!

Comment: My guess is the describeInstances is async

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Right now, you're calling decribeInstances multiple times for the same instance ID.

Comment: @jarmod this is just example code, the real code will pull different ids for the array, but the concept is the same.

Comment: @JimmyHodgson In that case, you should probably just supply all of the IDs in the InstanceIds array parameter and call describeInstances once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have already mentioned, `ec2.describeInstances` is asynchronous.

You need to know when all the async calls have completed. For this you can use a library like [Async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async#each). Here is an example:

```
var async = require('async');
var arr = { values: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'] };    

async.each(arr.values, function(element, callback) {
  ec2.describeInstances({ InstanceIds: ['i-51ec7d83'] }, function (err, data) {
    console.log(data.Reservations[0].Instances[0].Tags[0].Value);
    callback(); // <-- this lets it know the async operation is complete
  });
}, function() {
  console.log('Excecute this after.');
});
```

The 3rd argument to the `each` method is a `done` callback that will be called when all the async calls in the loop have completed.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I can't comment, but as Chris Muench has stated `describeInstances` is probably async since `Array.prototype.forEach` and `console.log` are synchronous.

According to the AWS Docs:

`All requests made through the SDK are asynchronous and use a callback interface. Each service method that kicks off a request can accept a callback as the last parameter with the signature function(error, data) { ... }. This callback will be called when the response or error data is available.`

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/node-making-requests.html
https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console